# jQuery: What is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first question here.
First of all have a look at this code

```
 $("body").on("click", "#showstore", function() {
    $('#foo a[href="' + $('.container').children('a').attr('href') + '"]').remove();
 });
```

HTML

```
<div id="showstore">Button</div>
<div id="foo">
  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">hello</a>
  <a href="http://google.com/">okay</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">bye</a>
  <a href="http://google.com/">see</a>
</div>
```

On clicking '#showstore' only the first 'a' is being removed. How can I make it remove all the matched 'a' from #foo?

jsFiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/xr3gjvxx/27/

Comment: What do you mean by *"only the first 'a' is being removed. How can I make it remove all the matched 'a'?"*?? If only the first `<a>` is being removed then that's it is what being matched by your selector. Explain which `<a>` you're trying to remove instead.

Comment: explain matched 'a'. do you mean all a tags in #foo div ?

Comment: Thanks TJ for your input. I want all the matched 'a' in #foo to be removed. Matching takes place between 'a's of .container and 'a's of #foo.

Comment: Yes @Farshad. All the matched a tags.

Comment: Again you're saying *I want all the **matched** 'a'* - What do you mean by *matched* a? Obviously your problem is that your selector isn't matching whatever you want to select.. then how could you say matched a.. ?!!

Comment: @Shikharsportal for remove all `a` tags is `#foo` div simply use `$('#foo a').remove();`

Comment: @TJ The first 'a' in both .container and #foo have same href value. Now the above code removes the first 'a' from #foo. But as you may see the second 'a' in both .container and #foo  also have same value. How to remove the second 'a' also? Do you get it?

Comment: @Shikharsportal yes, please update the question properly so that any future readers won't get lost...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

selector in your code is targeting anchor tags under `#foo`, that has to be changed to all anchor tags.

change

```
$('#foo a[href="' + $('.container').children('a').attr('href') + '"]').remove();
```

to

```
$('a[href="' + $('.container').children('a').attr('href') + '"]').remove();
```

#### update - 1

Your code is trying to remove all anchor tags under #foo which are having `href="http://jsfiddle.net/"` which is only one in your code above and gets removed. If you are trying to remove all the anchor tags under #foo irespective or the href value, then try

```
$('#foo a').remove();
```

#### update - 2

Ok if you need to loop over each child and remove the anchor tags, then try

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#showstore", function() {

    $('.container').children('a').each(function(){

        $('#foo a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').remove();

    });

});
```

Here is [**a sample fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xr3gjvxx/35/).

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I just want to remove matched 'a' from #foo.

Comment: You're almost there. But the second 'a' in both container also have same href value. How to remove them also?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container').children('a').attr('href')
```

is not returning an element. It is returning an array. It returns both two  in the container blocks. You have to run a loop to remove all the matching  's in container block.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#showstore", function() {
        var links = $('.container').children('a'),
            targets = $('#foo a');
    
        links.each(function(){
            targets.filter('[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').remove();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showstore">Button</div>
<div id="foo">
  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">hello</a>
  <a href="http://google.com/">okay</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">bye</a>
  <a href="http://google.com/">see</a>
</div>
```

You need to iterate over the matching `a` elements.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/xr3gjvxx/34/